# Why does the JavaBean adapter not update the JavaFX property?

Tags: javafx

I'm new to JavaFX and need a bidirectional binding between a GUI (using JavaFX properties) and my old Java code (**not** using JavaFX properties). I tried using a JavaBean adapter as the following simple example shows:

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.adapter.JavaBeanDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.adapter.JavaBeanDoublePropertyBuilder;

public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException
    {
        Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
        FXModel model = new FXModel();

        JavaBeanDoubleProperty adapter = JavaBeanDoublePropertyBuilder
                .create().bean(pojo).name("value").build();

        model.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(adapter);

        System.out.println("Adapter before: " + adapter.get());
        System.out.println("Model before: " + model.getValue());
        System.out.println("Bean before: " + pojo.getValue());

        pojo.setValue(123d);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Adapter after: " + adapter.get());
        System.out.println("Model after: " + model.getValue());
        System.out.println("Bean after: " + pojo.getValue());
    }

    public static class Pojo
    {
        private double value;

        public double getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(double value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static class FXModel
    {
        private final DoubleProperty value = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

        public double getValue()
        {
            return value.get();
        }

        public void setValue(double value)
        {
            this.value.set(value);
        }

        public DoubleProperty valueProperty()
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

The generated output is

> Adapter before: 0.0 Model before: 0.0 Bean before: 0.0
>
> Adapter after: 123.0 Model after: 0.0 Bean after: 123.0

So, by setting the "normal" Java object to a new value the JavaBeanDoubleProperty is informed about the change, but the JavaFX property is not, although it is bound to the adapter. Why?

Even by adding a PropertyChangeSupport to Pojo as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217407/how-does-javabeans-property-adapter-work),

```
public static class Pojo
    {
        private double value;
        private PropertyChangeSupport pcs;

        public Pojo()
        {
            pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
        }

        public double getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(double value)
        {
            final double oldValue = this.value;
            this.value = value;
            pcs.firePropertyChange("name", oldValue, value);
        }

        public void addPropertyChangeListener(
                final PropertyChangeListener listener)
        {
            pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
        }
    },
```

it does not work. (Unfortunately, a second trial using [BeanPathAdapter](http://ugate.wordpress.com/2012/07/30/javafx-programmatic-pojo-expression-bindings-part-iii/) also did not work.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just made a slip in `Pojo.setValue(double value)`. This method fires a PropertyChangeEvent for the property "name". It supposed to be "value".
Just change it to

```
public void setValue(double value)
{
    final double oldValue = this.value;
    this.value = value;
    pcs.firePropertyChange("value", oldValue, value);
}
```

and it will work.

Comment: Works, thanks. (I cannot yet vote up, since I have not enough reputations, but I'll do it another time.)

Answer (score 1):

The binding is supposed to be between the adapter and model. Do not modify the pojo values directly, the adapter will do the updating. Replacing the line:

```
pojo.setValue(123d);
```

with this,

```
adapter.setValue(123d);
```

results in the expected output with all values updated including the pojo. The same happens when you set the value of the model. The diagrams at this [post](http://tidalwave.it/fabrizio/blog/design/) may help you visualise the working.