# Full support for JavaFX properties in POJOs

Tags: java, properties, javafx, aspectj

There are quite a few questions on SO regarding adding JavaFX property support to existing POJO classes. Properties for those classes can be created by using adapters in [javafx.beans.property.adapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/adapter/package-summary.html) package. However, properties created in such way will not reflect changes made using setter methods of POJO classes, unless [PropertyChangeSupport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217407/how-does-javabeans-property-adapter-work) is added to POJO class.

Changing existing classes is sometimes not possible, and even when it is, adding PropertyChangeSupport can be extremely tedious if you have a lot of classes. So I wanted to share a way to do it which does not require changing existing classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is inspired by an [article](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/javaben/archive/2006/06/javabeans_bindi.html) by Ben Galbraith, and uses [AspectJ](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/). It requires absolutely no changes to existing model classes. Installing AspectJ is beyond the scope of this tutorial, suffice to say that all major IDEs support it (installing it in Eclipse is trivial).

This example assumes that all your model classes extend a base class, called BaseEntity in this case. If your implementation differs from that, you will of course need to adapt the aspect.

First, we will create an interface which defines methods needed for PropertyChangeSupport.

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

public interface ChangeSupport {
    // Add listener for all properties
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener);
    // Remove listener for all properties
    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener);
    // Add listener for specific property
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener);
    // Remove listener for specific property
    public void removePropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener);
    // Fire change event for specific property
    public void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object newValue);
    // Check if property has any listeners attached
    public boolean hasListeners(String propertyName);
}
```

Next, we will create an implementation of that interface.

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import com.mycompany.myapp.model.BaseEntity;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

public class ChangeSupportImpl implements ChangeSupport {
    // Declared transient as there is no need to serialize these fields
    private transient PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport;
    private final transient Object source;

    public ChangeSupportImpl() {
        super();
        this.source = this;
    }

    // Needed for annotation-style aspect
    public ChangeSupportImpl(final BaseEntity baseEntity) {
        super();
        this.source = baseEntity;
    }

    @Override
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(final PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        // PropertyChangeSupport is loaded lazily
        if (this.propertyChangeSupport == null)
            this.propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this.source);
        this.propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removePropertyChangeListener(final PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        if (this.propertyChangeSupport != null)
            this.propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(final String propertyName, final PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        // PropertyChangeSupport is loaded lazily
        if (this.propertyChangeSupport == null)
            this.propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this.source);
        this.propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removePropertyChangeListener(final String propertyName, final PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        if (this.propertyChangeSupport != null)
            this.propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void firePropertyChange(final String propertyName, final Object oldValue, final Object newValue) {
        if (this.propertyChangeSupport != null)
            this.propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(propertyName, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasListeners(final String propertyName) {
        return this.propertyChangeSupport != null && (this.propertyChangeSupport.hasListeners(propertyName)
                || this.propertyChangeSupport.hasListeners(null));
    }
}
```

Finally, we will create an aspect which adds PropertyChangeSupport to BaseEntity class. The aspect uses a custom class ReflectUtils to get the property's old value. You can use any utility you like, or plain old Java reflection (that may affect performance, though).

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import com.mycompany.myapp.model.BaseEntity;
import com.mycompany.myapp.util.ReflectUtils;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.DeclareMixin;

import java.util.Objects;

@Aspect
public class BaseEntityObservabilityAspect {
    @DeclareMixin("com.mycompany.myapp.model.BaseEntity")
    public static ChangeSupport createChangeSupportImplementation(final BaseEntity baseEntity) {
        return new ChangeSupportImpl(baseEntity);
    }

    // Intercept setters in all BaseEntity objects in order to notify about property change
    @Around("this(baseEntity) && execution(public void set*(*))")
    public void firePropertyChange(final BaseEntity baseEntity,
            final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        // Get property name from method name
        final String setterName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        final String property = setterName.substring(3, 4).toLowerCase() + setterName.substring(4);
        final ChangeSupport support = (ChangeSupport)baseEntity;
        if (support.hasListeners(property)) {
            // Get old value via reflection
            final Object oldValue = ReflectUtils.invokeGetter(baseEntity, property);

            // Proceed with the invocation of the method
            joinPoint.proceed();

            // New value is the first (and only) argument of this method
            final Object newValue = joinPoint.getArgs()[0];
            // Fire only if value actually changed
            if (!Objects.equals(oldValue, newValue))
                support.firePropertyChange(property, oldValue, newValue);
        } else {
            // No listeners have been registered with BaseEntity, so there is no need to fire property change event
            joinPoint.proceed();
        }
    }
}
```

If you cannot use annotation style for some reason, here is the same using AspectJ code style.

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import java.util.Objects;

import com.mycompany.myapp.model.BaseEntity;
import com.mycompany.myapp.util.ReflectUtils;

public aspect BaseEntityObservabilityAspect {
    declare parents: BaseEntity extends ChangeSupportImpl;

    // Intercept setters in all BaseEntity objects in order to notify about property change
    void around(final BaseEntity entity, final ChangeSupport support):
            this(entity) && this(support) && execution(public void BaseEntity+.set*(*)) {
        // Get property name from method name
        final String setterName = thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        final String property = setterName.substring(3, 4).toLowerCase() + setterName.substring(4);
        if (support.hasListeners(property)) {
            final Object oldValue;
            try {
                // Get old value via reflection
                oldValue = ReflectUtils.invokeGetter(entity, property);
            } catch (final Throwable e) {
                // Should not happen
                proceed(entity, support);
                return;
            }

            // Proceed with the invocation of the method
            proceed(entity, support);

            // New value is the first (and only) argument of this method
            final Object newValue = thisJoinPoint.getArgs()[0];
            // Fire only if value actually changed
            if (!Objects.equals(oldValue, newValue))
                support.firePropertyChange(property, oldValue, newValue);
        } else {
            // No listeners have been registered with BaseEntity, so there is no need to fire property change event
            proceed(entity, support);
        }
    }
}
```